# Error while running sqlplus after installing Oracle Client 11g R2 on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-11g

I am facing issue while running ./sqlplus command after installing Oracle Client 11g R2 on RHEL 7

here's is the error:

```
$ ./sqlplus
./sqlplus: symbol lookup error: /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1: undefined symbol: nnfyboot
```

I identified LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ORACLE_HOME, PATH

Also, all pre-req. packages have been isntalled.

Look at the below commands as well,

```
$ ldd
 /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
            linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff60ff9000)
            libnnz11.so => /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libnnz11.so (0x00007f8f85e62000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8f85c57000)
            libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8f85955000)
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8f85739000)
            libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f8f8551f000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8f8515e000)
            libaio.so.1 => /lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f8f84f5c000)
            /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8f88856000)
```

and this,

```
$ ldd sqlplus
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff54d4d000)
        libsqlplus.so => /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libsqlplus.so (0x00007f3d1e403000)
        libclntsh.so.11.1 => /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0x00007f3d1bdd7000)
        libnnz11.so => /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libnnz11.so (0x00007f3d1ba0f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3d1b805000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3d1b502000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3d1b2e6000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f3d1b0cd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3d1ad0b000)
        libaio.so.1 => /lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f3d1ab09000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3d1e5eb000)
```

ldconfig completed successfully.

Would you please help ?

Comment: Did you ignore some errors during the install/build stage ? Looks like some of your libraries weren't built properly (and yes, Oracle DB does build some binaries here and there during the installation stage).

Comment: I just ran runInstaller in silent mode and it didn't fail for pre-req. but log shows errors in make and some libraries .. how to fix this ?

Comment: Easy way - reinstall, but first fix the prereqs, some of them, like presence of various software, is vital. You can ignore only sysctl/file limits/swap/memory prereqs, but no others.

Comment: Plus, some errors are cause by the inconsistencies in the zero-point releases (which Oracle distributes freely from their site). But it's hard to guess what caused your errors without seeing the log part with build errors.

Comment: Same Software installed successfully on Centos 7 . .but can't be installed successfully on RHEL 7 .. That's what make me feel crazy now !

Comment: This means you have missing rpms on RHEL 7.